# Time series classification using CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a convolutional neural network which classifies time series data into two classes. For the time being I only have a small dataset so what I need first is to augment my datasets so I can feed them into a network.
For the data augmentation task, I found some very helpful methods at https://github.com/uchidalab/time_series_augmentation repository. What I have tried so far is to add some gaussian noise to my data, a permutation method, a time warping, a window slice and a window warp methods. These methods are being applied on a (batches, batch_rows, channels)=(354, 400, 3) dataset to generate a (1770, 400, 3) dataset (including train and test datasets and their corresponding labels).
Given the fact that I have a limited number of inputs, I would like to know if you have any suggestions for a 1D CNN structure for a good performance over these datasets.
What I have tried so far is this network:

```
verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 10, 8
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2], trainy.shape[1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))

model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit network
model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

# evaluate model
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
```

No matter the changes I make in the parameters and the hyperparameters, I always get an accuracy around 50%, meaning that a binary classifier does not exists.

I would really appreciate if anyone can tell me what probably is the problem. Does this happens due to poor data quality produced by the augmentation methods? Or is it has to do with the network itself?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If it's a classification between two classes, you should use binary_crossentropy as loss function.